Font embedding with Libreoffice (eps files)
I would like to generate an eps file with embedded fonts, to make sure that the font I am using in Linux (Nimbus Sans) will look the same when the file is opened on a non-Linux (e.g. Windows) PC. I am creating the file using Libreoffice Draw. I have two closely-related questions:

If I enable 'font embedding' in the Libreoffice file settings, is that just for saving the project as a .odg file, or will that also embed the fonts if I export to a .eps file?

Is there a simple way I can verify if the Nimbus Sans font did indeed get embedded in the exported .eps file?



in which software on windows are you opening the EPS file? I ask because EPS can embed different types of Fonts, and especially on windows software, support is spotty. Also, it's 2024 – it's unlikely that EPS is the format you want as portable document format…

@MarcusMüller I am submitting a paper to an academic journal, and they require figures to be submitted in EPS format. As for your first question: I'm not 100% sure, however I am submitting the figures for use with a Latex document, so they will presumably be processed using Latex in Windows. The journal's guidelines request fonts to be embedded, if standard 'postscript' fonts can't be used. So, I want to follow their guidelines, but would like to verify if the font embedding is being done.

oh, is that still a thing? huh! last time I was doing that, people were requesting things that could be built using pdflatex, and EPS figures were automatically converted to PDF for that purpose. But LaTeX capabilities are the same on Windows and other operating systems, so if your latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf chain generates a PDF that works on windows (and you can check the embedded fonts in adobe reader on windows, or in evince or atril on Linux), then you're fine. But really, double-check that they exclusively support latex, and not pdflatex, as is really the norm by now.

@MarcusMüller it seems likely they are using pdflatex, but I will check. I am also developing the document using Overleaf, so I will check that the fonts in the resulting PDF reproduce ok in Windows (or an online viewer). Thanks for your input!
